# SQL Query While uploading sql file

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, localhost

I was uploading localhost site to live server. During the process I was importing `.sql` file from localhost to PHPMyAdmin live server database. After the uploading process was complete I got an error of:

[image: Error message]

**SQL query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `core_email_queue_recipients`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_6F4948F3ABF97DE12127EF14B140802A`
FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`) REFERENCES `core_email_queue` (`message_id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

**MySQL said:**

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`buddydea_magento`.`#sql-2aae_84a13f`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_6F4948F3ABF97DE12127EF14B140802A` FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`)
>   REFERENCES `core_email_queue` (`message_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASC)

I have looked for the solution but didn't find the right answer.

Please help me to remove this error.

Comment: did you have ssh access? run commad mysqldump and import database

Answer (score 0):

Excute below query before upload

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Once uploaded revert back

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: how should i do this.

Comment: go to sql tab and run the query

Comment: I just have to go sql tab and run this command ?

Comment: yes.  just goo to the sql tab and past the SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; then click 'go' button

Comment: Did you get my point?

Comment: i have to put "checks=0"  or 1 ?

Comment: please explain me what this command will do and how will i know does this work or not ?

Comment: Don't bother about this query. This is mysql system variable for more information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html.  FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS. 1. Run SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 2.Upload your sql file 3. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;.

Comment: Again i have to upload the sql fie ? I have already imported that file and than this error came .

Comment: I have just run the command  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;  Do i need to update the sql file again and delete all the tables that were uploaded ? Because all the tables are already there.

Comment: No need to upload full database sql file. just extract core_email_queue_recipients table details from your db sql file and save new sql file like email.sql. then upload email.sql.finally do SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: will it go wrong if i will import the full database again?

Comment: Nope. you can do if you have time. better drop current databse and create new database with same name.then upload it.

Comment: Actually i have started uploading that file again.  I will finally run this command after uploading      SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: now i m getting duplicate entry

Comment: drop your db and import it

Comment: okay i m creating new one with running 3 steps you mentioned above.

Comment: I have Created the new db run the command SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; then upload the sql file but i got the same error again and then i ran SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; command . so error would have resolved ?

Comment: in my experience, set foreign key checks to zero does not fix the problem. There-s something off in the way phpmyadmin exports the data, and reimport locks up. See my answer below: export from magento's backup and then it will reimport in phpmyadmin fine. With foreign key checks to 0!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I export from phpmysql, even with "disable foreign key checks" set both at export and import, my import has been failing. Phpmysql is exporting in an order that makes no sense, creating the keys too early, or not destroying them when dropping the tables, and not ignoring the checks totally.

BUT THERE IS A WAY - if I export the database from within Magento's Backup tool - that file imports in phpmyadmin without errors.

Wish I'd tried that earlier